# Android 6.0 Firefox Change Default App for media type?

Tags: firefox-for-android

I pressed in Firefox "Open torrent file download in LibreTorrent" but I can not download torrent cuz I need be looged in. Now I don't know how to change it? I want Android Firefox download it with its Downloads option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to change the default downloading option, do the following:

Go into your phone settings>apps>LibreTorrent>set as default>clear defaults.

Now when you try to download again, Firefox should ask you which app to use for that action.

Comment: Thanks. But the app Libre Torrent says it has not any defaults. And it looks like Firefox doesn't have too. I ended up with reintalling the Torrent app.